# Чем модуль корзины покупок на AJAX лучше iframe

Tags: php, html, корзина

Почему принято писать корзину на ajax если можно сделать iframe в котором подгружается обработчик? Да и почему вообще в современной верстке редко используется iframe?
Пример работы: На товары вешаем ссылки с передачей GET методом id товара и отправляем это дело во фрейм target="_iframe1" с обработчиком, в обработчике ловим GET вытаскиваем с mysql цену наименование и т.д. по id товара и вгоняем это в сессию (и так каждую позицию). На странице оплаты вытаскиваем все данные из сессии и отправляем далее.

Comment: Так зачем нужен iframe, если ajax делает тоже самое: передаёт get-ом id, в обработчике вытаскивает из mysql цену, наименование и т.д., вгоняя всё это в сессию. ajax - более менее прямой путь выполнить задачу. iframe - через жопу. Ну не было раньше другого варианта, теперь есть.

Comment: в ajax код будет длиной строк так в 15-20 (в лучшем случае), во фрейме кода не будет вообще (кроме <iframe src= бла бла бла</iframe>) , будет тупо ссылка с концом "?id="

Comment: Эти 15-20 строк помещаются в одну функцию, которая вызывается так же в одну строку. Ну и 15-20 строк на простой GET c id - это Вы конечно немного преувеличили.

Comment: В таком случае подскажите пожалуйста решение проблемы с AJAX. Код передает значение value с заданного input в обработчик, но как сделать, чтоб отслеживался id откуда произошел клик и данные которые передаются соответственно менялись на данные из другого input? а то раскопировать данный код для 100 товаров на странице не очень удобно.

Comment: <input id="price" type="hidden" value="100">
<input type="submit" onclick="getAjax(); return false;" id="myForm" value="Рассчитать">
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function getAjax(){
$.ajax({
 url: "action.php", // путь к ajax файлу
 type: "POST",      // тип запроса
 data: { // действия
   id: $('#price').val()
 },
 // Данные пришли
 success: function( data ) {
   $( "#view" ).html( "<strong>" + data + "</strong>" );
  }
});
 
}
 
//]]>
</script>
 
<div id="view"></div>

Comment: P.S. в AJAX абсолютный ноль

Comment: Следовало бы задать отдельный вопрос. А так скажите как iframe загружает (или выгружает) нужный id? Разве он не тиражируется по 100 раз по всей странице? `iframe src = url?id=...` Чему равен id? Тоже самое надо передать в качестве параметра в функцию `getAjax()`, точнее вместо `getAjax()` будет `getAjax(id)` с `data : { 'id' : id }`. Коль скоро применяете jquery, то можно и без доп. функции обойтись. `onclick="$.get( 'url', { 'id': id } ); return false;"`. Если нужен именно `GET`, о котором много говорилось, а не `POST`, который неожиданно появился.

Comment: через iframe все проще: на каждом товаре ссылка собственно в корзину выглядит так: <a href="action.php?id=1">в корзину</a> <a href="action.php?id=2">в корзину</a> и т.д.. Насчет post косякнул, там пример рабочего скрипта, сменить метод забыл.

Comment: и правда работает... пожалуй теперь можно убрать любимые фреймы на пыльную полку. Спасибо Вам Сергей огромное!

Comment: Тогда самое простое что приходит на ум `<a href="#" onckick="$.get( 'action.php', { 'id': 1 } ); return false;">в корзину</a> <a href="#" onckick="$.get( 'action.php', { 'id': 2 } ); return false;">туда же</a>`

Comment: а как используя onclick="$.get( 'action.php', { 'id': 1 } ); return false;" добиться обновления div с корзиной без перезагрузки?

Comment: `onclick="$.get( 'action.php', { 'id': 1 }, updateCart ); return false;"` где `updateCart` - это Ваша функция обновления корзины. Должна разобрать ответ сервера и соответственно ему обновить div с корзиной. Будут отличия от обработки iframe, но думаю не значительные. А при некоторых условиях можно даже упростить (используя json-ответ). См. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ Я ведь тоже не ахти какой специалист по javascript. Лучше спросить конкретные вопросы, уверен найдётся кто ответит лучше.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, выручили!